# How can I use FileSystemWatcher from System.IO.Abstractions to monitor a mock filesystem?

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to create a class to monitor USB device arrivals and removals on Linux. On Linux, USB devices are represented as device files under `/dev/bus/usb` which are created/deleted in response to these events.

It seems the best way to track these events is using `FileSystemWatcher`. To make the class testable, I'm using [`System.IO.Abstractions`](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) and injecting an instance of `IFileSystem` to the class during construction. What I want is to create something that behaves like a `FileSystemWatcher` but monitors changes to the injected `IFileSystem`, not the real file-system directly.

Looking at `FileSystemWatcherBase` and `FileSystemWatcherWrapper` from `System.IO.Abstractions`, I'm not sure how to do this. At the moment I have this (which I know is wrong):

```
public DevMonitor(
    [NotNull] IFileSystem fileSystem,
    [NotNull] IDeviceFileParser deviceFileParser,
    [NotNull] ILogger logger,
    [NotNull] string devDirectoryPath = DefaultDevDirectoryPath)
{
    Raise.ArgumentNullException.IfIsNull(logger, nameof(logger));
    Raise.ArgumentNullException.IfIsNull(devDirectoryPath, nameof(devDirectoryPath));

    _fileSystem = fileSystem ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileSystem));
    _deviceFileParser = deviceFileParser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(deviceFileParser));
    _logger = logger.ForContext<DevMonitor>();
    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcherWrapper(devDirectoryPath);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what the downvote is for?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. FileSystemWatcher class is not extensible at all (doesn't even have any useful virtual methods). Instead - abstract away FileSystemWatcher behind some interface which has `Created` etc events and in your unit tests fire those events manually. So after adding directory to your `IFileSystem` - fire corresponding event yourself.

Comment: That's one way but I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to that. I wasn't expecting them to directly extend `FileSystemWatcher`, but maybe to have something along the lines of a factory `IFileSystem => IFileSystemWatcher` which checked if the provided `IFileSystem` is real or a mock. If real, then return a wrapper around the standard `FileSystemWatcher`. If mock, then return a custom class that monitors changes to the mock file system.

Comment: I guess you have to implement that yourself, or file github issue about that and hope author will implement it. There is issue about implementing mock FileSystemWatcher already: https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions/issues/167, which is 1 year old, so I'd not expect fast results.

Comment: Ah, cheers. That sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of the fact that `System.IO.Abstractions` doesn't seem to support this yet, I went with this:

I defined an `IWatchableFileSystem` interface that extends `IFileSystem`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a(n) <see cref="IFileSystem" /> that can be watched for changes.
/// </summary>
public interface IWatchableFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <c>FileSystemWatcher</c> that can be used to monitor changes to this file system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <c>FileSystemWatcher</c>.</returns>
    FileSystemWatcherBase CreateWatcher();
}
```

For production purposes I implement this as `WatchableFileSystem`:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public sealed class WatchableFileSystem : IWatchableFileSystem
{
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WatchableFileSystem" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public WatchableFileSystem() => _fileSystem = new FileSystem();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DirectoryBase Directory => _fileSystem.Directory;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDirectoryInfoFactory DirectoryInfo => _fileSystem.DirectoryInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDriveInfoFactory DriveInfo => _fileSystem.DriveInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public FileBase File => _fileSystem.File;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IFileInfoFactory FileInfo => _fileSystem.FileInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public PathBase Path => _fileSystem.Path;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public FileSystemWatcherBase CreateWatcher() => new FileSystemWatcher();
}
```

Within my unit test class I implement it as `MockWatchableFileSystem` which exposes `MockFileSystem` and `Mock<FileSystemWatcherBase>` as properties which I can use for arranging & asserting within my tests:

```
private class MockWatchableFileSystem : IWatchableFileSystem
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public MockWatchableFileSystem()
    {
        Watcher = new Mock<FileSystemWatcherBase>();
        AsMock = new MockFileSystem();

        AsMock.AddDirectory("/dev/bus/usb");
        Watcher.SetupAllProperties();
    }

    public MockFileSystem AsMock { get; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DirectoryBase Directory => AsMock.Directory;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDirectoryInfoFactory DirectoryInfo => AsMock.DirectoryInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDriveInfoFactory DriveInfo => AsMock.DriveInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public FileBase File => AsMock.File;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IFileInfoFactory FileInfo => AsMock.FileInfo;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public PathBase Path => AsMock.Path;

    public Mock<FileSystemWatcherBase> Watcher { get; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public FileSystemWatcherBase CreateWatcher() => Watcher.Object;
}
```

Finally, in my client class I can just do:

```
public DevMonitor(
    [NotNull] IWatchableFileSystem fileSystem,
    [NotNull] IDeviceFileParser deviceFileParser,
    [NotNull] ILogger logger,
    [NotNull] string devDirectoryPath = DefaultDevDirectoryPath)
{
    // ...
    _watcher = fileSystem.CreateWatcher();

    _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    _watcher.Path = devDirectoryPath;
}
```

During tests, the client gets an `IWatchableFileSystem` that wraps `MockFileSystem` and returns a mock instance of `FileSystemWatcherBase`. During production, it gets an `IWatchableFileSystem` that wraps `FileSystem` and generates unique instances of `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: If I were to call the .AsMock.AddFile method at a later time, would that invoke the Created event?